# Булевы значения/тригеры для недвоичных систем

Tags: binary, cpu, олимпиада, биоинформатика

Планируем провести цикл занятий со школьниками 5-8 классов с популяризацией биоинформатики и биокомпьютеров. В частности, будут практические занятия по созданию биокомпьютеров с переменной логикой. Будут представлены простейшие биокомпьютеры с двоичной, троичной, четверичной и пятеричной логикой. Основные арифметические операции уже определены и прописаны, споры идут по логическим операциям. Для двоичной логики всё понятно, для троичной - к ЛОЖЬ и ИСТИНА добавляется ВЕРОЯТНО, а вот что добавить ПОЛЕЗНОГО в случае четверичной и пятеричной логики?

Comment: Возвращаясь к этой теме: у нас в качестве побочного "продукта" при исследовании искусственных живых тканей получился эдакий биокомпьютер с шестиричной логикой. Так вот, есть успешный эксперимент по его приложению к токарному станку.

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov, да читал ваш стенд на "Биотехнологии". Думаю, добавлю в качестве примера в свои лекции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, я буду неправ, но два других значения пригодились бы в случае решения задач в области комплексных чисел, когда необходимо разбивать области решений на положительную, отрицательную и {+i, -i} или {+i}, {-i}.
Конечно, это вряд ли подойдёт для школьников, тем более у вас уклон в биоинформатику, но стоит тег - "олимпиада", что предполагает умных детей.

Comment: В таком направлении мы не думали :) Вряд ли комплексные числа подойдут для школьников, но аналогия в геометрии просматривается. Спасибо!