# Расширение списка команд для биокомпьютера

Tags: ассемблер, cpu, олимпиада, биоинформатика

В учебных целях (научить школьников и студентов работать с оборудованием и реагентами, ставить эксперименты) мы придумали биокомпьютер. Логика у него, как я упоминал в теме "[Булевы значения/тригеры для недвоичных систем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749446/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC)" может быть от двоичной до пятиричной. Число регистров, формально, любое, но бесконечными ресурсами мы не обладаем, поэтому проще заявить, что количество регистров - 8, количество "адресуемых ячеек памяти" - не более 100. Эти сто ячеек могут ссылаться на массивы практически любой длины (тоже разумно ограничены) с разрядностью 4 бита на ячейку (AGTC).
На данный момент мы "научили" его делать следующие целочисленные арифметические операции: ADD, SUB, MUL, причем команды могут выполняться как с регистрами, так и с двумя массивами одновременно - то есть c[i]:= a[i]+b[i];  логические операции AND, NOT, OR (также есть возможность проводить их с массивами); безусловный переход JMP; условные переходы на равенство регистров, на их неравенство, на равенство регистра нулю. Сейчас работаем над побитовым сдвигом влево и вправо.

Разумеется, реализованы команды обмена между регистрами и памятью. Правда, они самые медленные.

Из указанного набора команд можем ли мы создать другие операции, в частности, интересует операция деления?

**Update 1**

Да, забыл упомянуть одно важное условие: мы не можем совершать над одним или парой регистров подряд одно и то же арифметическое действие более 5-6 раз. Да, можно перенести результат в другой регистр, но это очень медленно (работа руками, фактически).

**Update 2**

О регистрах. Регистр очень похож на классический ассемблерный, но там AL - младший байт, AH -старший, AX - два байта. У нас так же, но можно еще обращаться к любому из полубайтов, даже к старшим.
Ну, и флаги у нас не взводятся, совсем. Если сложить полубайтами 9 и 9 и результат запрашивать полубайтом же, получится 4. Никакой флаг взведён не будет.

**Update 3**

реализовали сдвиг вправо и влево сразу на 4 бита, как циклический, так и с заполнением нулями. Повторять можно любое количество раз. Побитовый пока не знаем как сделать (только влево - через умножение на 2, "дешевле" не получается) . Флаги по-прежнему не взводятся никакие :)

Comment: Очевидно, при наличии `sub` и условных переходов деление делается просто :)

Comment: Он не программный, всё происходит буквально "в пробирке", точнее, в нескольких десятках пробирок. Проблема в том, что мы не можем многократно повторять одно и то же арифметическое действие, то есть, сложить или вычесть два регистра мы можем подряд ну раз 5-6, не более. Можно результат перенести в другой регистр, но это очень медленно.

Comment: А на сколько у вас не ограничены массивы. может сделать какие то таблицы деления. только есть ли у вас операция взятия конкретного элемента и массива

Comment: @Mike  8 массивов по 100 полубайтов - реально. Адресовать можно каждый полубайт. Можно и длиннее, но тогда надо сильно "чесать репу" в плане адресации

Comment: Кстати, для деления в процессорах что то такое и используется, правда 
 иногда с некоторыми проблемами https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_Pentium_FDIV :)  Правда боюсь у этих таблиц размер все таки большой. Как бы целая хромосома для хранения не понадобилась :)

Comment: @Mike :D Нет, используются стандартные библиотеки по 100 нуклеотидов. Фактически, я лукавлю, что можно получить любой массив - мы не миллионеры. Но учащийся получает знания и может проверить на имеющихся стандартах свои идеи и свои "шаловливые ручки" :)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что биокомпьютер у вас, фактически, реализован посредством последовательностей реакций в микропробирках? И планировать операции нужно заранее, а "операнды" закапываются пипетками в пробирки?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov В целом, да. В каких-то моментах мы можем исключить ручной труд - посредством автокапельниц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С удовольствием слежу за вашими вопросами в биоинформатике. Собственно, у меня идея, если еще не опоздал, как можно сделать деление на базе именно молекулярной биологии, а не ориентируюясь на уже созданные ассемблерные команды.
Как я понимаю, регистр у вас - это пробирка или набор, все изменения вы проводите in vitro. Если я прав, можно деление на n представить как разбавление в n раз, а затем взятие аликвоты того же объема: концентрация упадет в n раз, вы получите частное от целочисленного деления. Можно подумать, как получить остаток.
Если концентрацию вы определяете по свечению зондов, это, на мой взгляд, хорошее решение.

Comment: Нет, не опоздали. Начинаем в понедельник. Хм... Да, пожалуй, увлекшись непосредственно информатикой, мы упустили такой подход из виду. Правда, разбавление как процесс мы не планировали, но можно и пересмотреть подход к снаряду. Спасибо!